# Freeradius SQLCounter

Tags: sql, freeradius

I'm using the SQL module of Freeradius to check if a user has reached it's weekly data limit, for that I'm using this query:

`SELECT (IFNULL(SUM(AcctInputOctets), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(AcctOutputOctets), 0)) as used_data FROM (SELECT * FROM radacct b WHERE username = '%{%k}' AND DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%u') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%u') GROUP BY acctuniqueid) a`

Now `'%{%k}'` is replaced by Freeradius with the users' username, but `%u` is also replaced, which should not happen as it should be processed by SQL to use the week number.

`%Y` is not touched by Freeradius.

Any ideas on how to make the query so that Freeradius won't escape this?

Comment: Hmm, double quoting `"` instead of single quotes `'` made sure Freeradius won't touch the variable. Consider it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct escape sequence is `%%u`. The `%%` prevents it being interpreted as a single letter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use Like This
%{User-Name}

Comment: nas_query = "SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM ${nas_table}"